# pygame - output name and scores to screen using for loop

Tags: python, pygame

I am doing a highscore in pygame; would like to check, how to we output the names and score to screen.
Right now I am able to grab the content from the file and output on screen.However, the data all displayed together in 1 line.
I tried to write "\n", but it doesn't work.
I am new to pygame, can someone help me out?

My code

```
f = open("score.txt",'r')
for line in f:
    column = line.split("\t")
    names = column[0]
    scores = int(column[2])
    scoreArray.append(scores)
    nameArray.append(names)
    data = list(zip(scoreArray,nameArray))
l = heapsort(data)


for i in l:
//output on screen
    score = smallfont.render("\n "+ str(i[0]), True, Color.black)
    nameRect = diskSurf.get_rect()
    nameRect.midtop = (width / 2, height / 2)
    screen.blit(score, nameRect)

    score = smallfont.render("\n "+ str(i[1]), True, Color.black)
    nameRect = diskSurf.get_rect()
    nameRect.midtop = (width / 2, height / 2)
    screen.blit(score, nameRect)

    print i[1] , "\t", i[0] // in the command line
```

The output I wanted is

```
Name            Score 
abc               2
cde               5
ffd               10
```

but the output I have now is 1 on top of another in the same line

Edit code:

```
for i in l, range (0,520, 10):
    screen.blit(smallfont.render(str(i[0]), True, Color.gray),(200,190))
    screen.blit(smallfont.render(str(i[1]), True, Color.gray),(500,190))
    print i[1] , "\t", i[0]
```

this code print out the value like this:

```
Name            Score 
(2,'abc')
```

Comment: You are using `nameRect.midtop = (width / 2, height / 2)` to position the text in every call. Assuming width and height are the screen width and height, you are telling pygame to put every text box in exactly the same place - the middle of the screen.

Comment: Go and try something, then post the results here

Comment: A good starting point would be to get the name and score to display on the left and right sides...

Comment: I'm able to display the name on the left and right by setting a coordinate for it. (:

Comment: screen.blit(smallfont.render(str(i[0]), True, Color.gray),(200,200))
        screen.blit(smallfont.render(str(i[1]), True, Color.gray),(500,200))

this is my code

Comment: @TomDalton  is it somethinglike this?         screen.blit(smallfont.render(str(i[1]), True, Color.gray),(200,len(l)*200))

Comment: That looks better, but the Y-position of the text needs to change. I think you're using `len(l)*200` for the y-position, which will always be the same value. I think part of the problem (for me at least) is that your variable names are really unhelpful. Maybe consider renaming `l` to `name_scores` or something similar? Then instead of `for i in l:`, you could have `for player_name, score in name_scores:`. I'll add an answer below expanding on that

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I have not tested this!**

```
with open("score.txt",'r') as f:
    name_scores = []
    for line in f:
        row = line.split("\t")
        player_name = row[0]
        score = int(row[2])
        name_scores.append((name, score))

name_scores.sort(key=lambda name_score: name_score[1], reverse=True)

for i in xrange(len(name_scores)):
    player_name, score = name_scores[i]
    x_name = 200
    x_score = 500
    y = 10 * i

    name_pos = (x_name, y)
    score_pos = (x_score, y)

    name_sprite = smallfont.render(player_name, True, Color.gray)
    score_sprite = smallfont.render(score, True, Color.gray)

    screen.blit(name_sprite, name_pos)
    screen.blit(score_sprite, score_pos)
```

Comment: Hi, I've this error, pointing at for i in len(name_scores): where is state that "int object is not iterable"

Comment: Hi, thanks.. There's still error with the render as "text must be string or unicode" , will try to fix it..